# MySQL connection with Java and Gradle

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, jdbc

I tried to connect to my MySQL database (Version 14.4 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64)) in my Java 10 project. This is how I get the driver via gradle (snapshot of my build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11'
}
```

This is the class I use to connect to my database:

```
package database;

import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseConnection {

private Connection conn = null;

public DatabaseConnection() {

}
private boolean openConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("MySQL driver couldn't be loaded!");
        }
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database",
                                       "user","pw");
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean closeConnection() {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean createUser(String userID, String username) {
    if (!openConnection())
        return false;
    try {
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();  
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table(User Name, UserID) VALUES("+username+","+userID+")"); 
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        closeConnection();
        return false;
    }
    closeConnection();
    return true;        
}
```

}

It always fails with

```
MySQL driver couldn't be loaded!
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228
    at database.DatabaseConnection.openConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:2)
    at database.DatabaseConnection.createUser(DatabaseConnection.java:39)
    at connect.GameServer.start(GameServer.java:31)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

The exception thrown at `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");` is a ClassNotFoundException.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, as it is stated to be correct in many tutorials, doesn't work either

Comment: Is this failing in your IDE or only in your deployment environment? If the latter, you have not included the dependency in your deploy package.

Comment: It is the latter. How do I do that with Gradle? I'm fairly new to it. Currently, I just run the buildNeeded task with Gradle Buildship for Eclipse to create a .jar file

Comment: Figured it out, I added task fatJar(type: Jar) {
 manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',  
         'Implementation-Version': version,
         'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

Comment: Running that and changing implementation to compile in the dependencies added the library to my jar file

Comment: You really shouldn't be creating fatjars. Especially when using libraries that include services definitions (like JDBC drivers). Just specify a correct classpath (either in the manifest or on the command line).